# What is the best option to host restful api and web site to access it?

Tags: php, hosting, backend

i made a restful API in native php that can handle all requests like GET, POST, PUTCH and DELETE, and a web-site to make this requests. I'm hosting it on my localmachine and the problem comes when I want to host all this things in the Internet. I find out that not every free service let you to host API, so that I need to use something called "Cloud service" like Heroku or AWS. And I stacked with all this massive documentation about deploying web apps.

So, my question is: are there some simple free or cheap host services where I can just upload folders and host both API and front part like in XAMPP?

Answer (score 0):

While this is not really a technical question and rather some advice on which service to host a website, the short answer is **"yes, what you was for exists"**.

You can find many "**mutualized hosting**" with built-in php support and ftp to "upload folders". Those are usually at a cost of $25~ a year. With most offers will come a SQL database and sometimes a domain.

As i'm not affiliate with any I won't give any name, but just google "mutualized php hosting" and you'll be good to go.